How to change Linux kernel to wait longer at UART before returning from read()?
I'm reading data from UART, running Linux 6.1 on i.MX6 ULL embedded device. No canonical mode, just raw data. termios::c_cc[VMIN] = 0, termios::c_cc[VTIME] = 20, so read() returns whenever at least one byte received or when 20 deciseconds timeout expires (I really need this timeout, see below).
One packet is 200 bytes, sent 100 times per second. I pass 200 to read() as count of bytes to expect first, then after read() call returns number of bytes received, next time I pass lesser value, etc. until all 200 bytes received.
When baudrate used is 921600 baud, read() function returns 6-12 times per packet, i.e. every read() call reads roughly 17-33 bytes.
When baudrate used is 460800 baud, read() function returns 12-24 times per packet.
So, my conclusion is: there is some nearly constant time interval in Linux code when data accumulated before read() returns. Let's call it "accumulating time".
Not surprisingly, switching process 12-24 times per packet loads CPU ~2 times more than 6-12 times (and that is serious load for i.MX6 ULL - more than 20%). So I get weird situation where I have to choose between reliability (lower baudrate) and CPU load, while intuitively low baudrate should not have any drawbacks.
How to increase that "accumulating time" in Linux code to wait longer before returning from read()? I understand that it would reduce responsiveness, but in this situation I don't need it as much (at least, I don't need to know that something received 24 times per packet).
In fact, I need very easy capability from the kernel: unblock my thread only when specified count of bytes received, or when specified timeout expires; as effective as possible.
I'm experienced in fixing Linux drivers (so, building Linux, readying it's code, configuring and extending DeviceTree etc.), but this time I gave up with searching "accumulating time" value (too much code to read and understand), and I really need help from someone who is already familiar with all that code.
I believe "accumulating time" value is in general Linux tty/UART-related code, or in specific i.MX6 ULL UART driver, so my first entry points were:
drivers/tty/n_tty.c
drivers/tty/serial/imx.c

although, without any success with searching.
In case someone would suggest specifying both termios::c_cc[VTIME] and termios::c_cc[VMIN]. When VMIN is not 0, meaning of VTIME actually differs: timeout is counted from first byte received, not from read() call. So if no data received at all, read() never returns.
Some additional notes.
Architecture of our application implies single dedicated thread for every UART port (we use 7 of them, that's why CPU load is so essential). Also, we need to detect stopping of sending data from outside, that's why using termios::c_cc[VTIME] timeout is critical. I understand that the thread loop could be organized different: sleep for, let's say, 100 ms in loop, and check for bytes available at UART every time; that could let achieve both collecting packets and implementing the timeout. But first, there are few nuances of our application (I could explain more in needed), which make this solution reducing the quality of the application and of the codebase quite sensitively. And second, I expect(ed) the kernel could implement the same much more effectively.
I've tested another approach: instead of using read() with termios::c_cc[VTIME] specified, I could wait in poll() (or epoll()) with timeout passed as argument, and call read() after it, with both termios::c_cc[VMIN] = termios::c_cc[VTIME] = 255. The results of using poll() (or epoll()) are the same: my thread unblocks the same number of times per packet as with naked read(). Actually, currently I use approach with poll() in my code because it allows more fine and dynamic control on timeout value; but for asking the question I used read() approach because it demonstrates the problem in simpler way.
May be one would be more pleasured to answer knowing the device we are working on is medical (electrocardiography).

RX FIFO on i.MX6 ULL is 32 bytes. You have to read buffer as soon as possible to prevent overrun and data loss. There is no advantage to create separate thread for each UART on a single-core system. Wait for data on all descriptors in a single epoll call, read it into your software buffers and trigger further processing when received enough.

Also you can take a look at fsl,dma-info option for the driver.

@dimich Thank you for the answer.
imx UART driver uses DMA. Normally, it's allowed to pass to DMA address in RAM where to store received DATA and the maximum amount (without limitation) to be stored. At least, that's true for STM32 MCUs. Why should user care of FIFO buffer? If DMA is not used, someone should core, but it is kernel who can move from FIFO to some buffer in RAM, providing user accumulated data of requested length. Are you sure Linux does not provide such trivial functionality?
When c_cc[VMIN] is 255, read() returns data at chunks of fixed length of 64, which is more than 32.

@dimich I can't use single thread with single epoll() for our application for few reasons.

It does not allow to control if there is no data at specific UART port for specified timeout. That is critical.
For some UART ports ("important" ones), we have to collect timestamps when the packet is received, as precise as possible. So we can't allow code which handles data from other UARTs to occupy CPU for some time solely. We assign higher realtime priority to threads handling "important" UARTS, so they can interrupt not important ports data handling, and get more precise timestamps.


@dimich 3. Having single epoll() does not solve my problem at all - that single thread would be unblocked as often as all my multiple threads cumulatively now.

@dimich At baudrate 460800 baud, read() returns chunks of 8 - 16 bytes, which is less than 32. If that amount would be caused by FIFO length, it could not depend on baudrate value. So I'm almost sure it is some time period specified somewhere in kernel which causes splitting data into such little chunks.

There is also tty driver on top of UART driver with it's own buffers and line discipline. With multiple threads CPU wakes up on each event anyway but also envolves scheduler to manage your threads and makes some context switching overhead. To manage individual timeouts you can add timerfd object for each uart into your poll/epoll set and re-arm timer when data received. Anyway, for such high precision and low latency as you perhaps want, I wouldn't rely on tty API in non-realtime OS.

The "some nearly constant time interval in Linux code when data accumulated before read() returns" is simply the processing time between the read() syscalls, You're searching for an "accumulating time value" in the kernel drivers that does not exist.

How to increase that "accumulating time" in Linux code to wait longer before returning from read()?

There is nothing in Linux kernel code to change or "increase".
Your successive read() syscalls are not instantaneous, so there is no need for the kernel "to wait ... before returning".
Rather the syscall overhead to return to userspace, your program's execution time to process the data and issue another (poll() and then) read(), and the syscall overhead to enter kernel mode add up to the (minimum) time interval to receive/accumulate the bytes that are returned immediately.
You could extend the time between the read() syscalls in your program though.
But you really cannot synchronize userspace processing with external I/O.

You might be asking an XY question.
IMO you are overloading the termios configuration for a "read with timeout" to perform two purposes:
(1) fetch data from the serial terminal as fast as possible with low overhead, and
(2) detect if there's no response or a disconnect.
Have you tried to separate these two goals?
For #1, use VMIN=200 and VTIME=1 to try to fetch an entire message.
For #2, accept the fact that a read() with interbyte timeout could block. Have each reading thread indicate to a monitoring thread that it read a message. So if a read() blocks, then no indication is sent, and the monitor thread takes whatever action.

Your answer is perfect, thank you so much! The situation I get is really simple, sadly I didn't realize myself what happens - because I thought 17-33 bytes at "slow" UART is too long for just executing syscalls and process switching. But 921600 baud is not so slow, so the time is 150-300 microseconds, which is quite reasonable for those activities.

I'm going to implement inserting nanosleep() between poll() and read() calls. Baudrate is known, so it's easy to calculate (probably with a margin found in experiments) time interval to sleep before all the data of single packet received, so single call to read() will happen. That would satisfy all the needs of our application.

Your suggestions on how to separate goals is good; it allows to avoid 2nd process switching (one for poll() and one for nanosleep()), but it has too much drawbacks in my case: 1. How to unblock the thread outside when it runs infinite read() (upon external UART sender hanging)? Would closing the file descriptor work? 2. In fact, when VMIN=200 and VTIME is not 0, read() returns data by chunks of 64 bytes (fixed size), not whole packet. Do you know what constant it is? 3. Writing data to the same containers from 2 different threads is not easy to manage. 4. Rewriting existing codebase required.

"when VMIN=200 and VTIME is not 0, read() returns data by chunks of 64 bytes" - How many different VTIME values did you actually test before you came up with this generalization? For VTIME = 1, that might be understandable; but greater than 5 then that has to be considered a bug. The intent of the interbyte timeout is to detect the idle time that typically follows a packet. But this timer is done at the tty layer rather than by the UART driver. "Do you know what constant it is?" - It might be related to your DMA configuration. What's in your Device Tree's UART node for fsl,dma-info?

I've tested VTIME = 255 only, it produces those 64 bytes chunks.
I don't specify fsl,dma-info, so both values are defaults, i.e. rx_period_length = 1024, rx_periods = 16.
